# cronjob [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] returns command not found

Tags: debian, cron, php

I'm running PHP 5.6 on an Debian 8 machine and hence there is a cronjob running as root for cleaning up session data:

```
09,39 * * * * root [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean
```

Did not even know I had this cronjob until last week when I started to get mails regarding this cronjob saying:

```
/bin/sh: 1: root: not found
```

When I try to run the above commands the command starting with "-x" fails:

```
-bash: -x: command not found
```

What does the -x in

```
[ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ]
```

mean? Any idea why I'm getting this error/mail?

Comment: Which cron do you use? User (via `crontab -e`) or system (in /etc/crontab or /etc/cron.)?

Comment: I can view/edit the cronjob via "sudo crontab -e" or by logging in as root and "crontab -e".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using the system-wide crontab `/etc/crontab`, there is no user field:

Sample user crontab file:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
...
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

As you can see the `user` field is missing.

The `-x` tests if file `/usr/lib/php5/sessionclean` exists and is executable. Without the username field you could also write:

```
09,39 * * * * test -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean
```

But your version should work as well without username field.

Comment: The file /etc/crontab does not contain the job/command, so I guess I'm not using the system-wide crontab...
I removed the username and now it seems to work. At least I'm not getting any mails indicating otherwise. But why did the job/command stop working? It has been working for two years (system install date) and the job/command was created by Apache/PHP/Debian (don't know which one actually creates the cronjob).